# Meta tag box has lower z index than footer, so appears below when question box is expanded

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here I have my question box expanded so it pushes down the footer. I then click the tags box, and *it's below the footer*:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Here is an animation:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

No other site does this - in all others the suggestions box appears *over* the footer (Meta.SE pictured here):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

It also works correctly on Workplace.SE, the site with the most (?) similar css design to here.

Comment: Good catch. This should be fixed now as part of the [recent site updates to base.less](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed).